# Pyplot is too slow when plotting point by point

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, graph

I have too many points(x,y) (about *280million*) to store in a list of x and a list of y and then feed to pyplot.scatter().

So I thought I could send x,y point by point. But pyplot.scatter is very slow to process this.

Are there any alternatives? My end game is to save the graph of points as an image.

Comment: try http://datashader.org/

Comment: Same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48854574/upper-limit-of-points-pyplot)?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, Yes in fact. turns out I can't use datashader wihout anaconda as well.